# What is the url for Facebook Open id endpoint?

Tags: facebook, openid, endpoint

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id this is the open id endpoint for google. I understand that facebook has no open id endpoint. Is there any way to login into my website by using the facebook credentials?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Thank you @miku: developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login - whilw i'm using this line as my command argument, the following error was occuring - "No OpenID endpoint found". How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use facebook login but you can't use facebook credentials in your site.

Comment: Agarwal: Thank you for your guidance. What do you mean by facebook login. I want to login into my own website using facebook username and password instead of my google credential. Is it possible?

Comment: Aravazhi: No not possible you can use facebook login window and facebook login process for that. Because facebook can't gives us permission to input facebook's credential into our site page.

Comment: Agarwal: Exactly. I agree with you. By clicking a button of my page, should redirected to facebook login page and return to my home page after authentication. I'm searched a lot to do this, couldn't get  any improvements. Plz help me to reach my destination.